# Check if user is over 18 using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm using Facebook to login users to a website.  At the moment I'm using the example code by facebook(below).  This works fine and returns the user name with a success message but I need to check if they are over 18 or not using age_range graph api call.  However I can't work out from the developer docs how to do this.  Can anyone help?

```
<script>
// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);
// The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
// app know the current login status of the person.
// Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
// for FB.getLoginStatus().
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
} else {
  // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
  // they are logged into this app or not.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
}
}

// This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
// Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
// code below.
function checkLoginState() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : '{your-app-id}',
cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                    // the session
xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
});

// Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
// FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
// person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
// the callback you provide.  They can be:
//
// 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
// 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
// 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
//    your app or not.
//
// These three cases are handled in the callback function.

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
statusChangeCallback(response);
});

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
// successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is   made.
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
 });
  }
</script>

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email"    onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I changed

```
/me
```

to

```
/me?fields=age_range
```

Then I get the minimum age range value like this

```
response.age_range.min
```

So I can do

```
 if(response.age_range.min >=18){
 //if user age range is greater or equal to 18 do something here
}
```

I hope this is helpful to someone else.